# Efficient way to move QGraphicItems inside QGraphicsScene

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I am developing a video player using pyqt5. I am using QGraphicsVideoItem inside a scene. On top of this videoitem, I also need to have some polygons that move around the scene on each new frame. They track things in the video. Ideally I wan't to get them to move with 30 fps. I did a test run, where I moved 1 polygon by 1 pixel at a speed of 30 fps. I did this with the setPos() function in the QGraphicsPolygonItem. This works, but it is very wonky and each time the polygon you can see it flashing white before being repainted. I think this happens because I am moving it too quickly. Also, this action is running in parallel in a thread.

What I want to know is if there is a way move the polygon the same way it moves when you turn on the "QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable" and "QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable" flags and move the item manually. This is very smooth and is what I would like to achieve.

I also tried leaving the points as stationary and instead moving the QGraphicsVideoitem around, this kinda worked (the move was steadier and there was no flashing white) but I could not get the scene to be centered on the videoItem. I tried using "setFocus", but this did not work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In these cases it is not advisable to move the item in each frame pixel by pixel, it is better to move every n frames so that the movement is smooth since the route must be interpolated for it can be used QVariantAnimation, in the following example the polygon randomly every 300ms.

```
import random
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class GraphicsPolygonItem(QtWidgets.QGraphicsPolygonItem):
    def moveTo(self, next_pos, duration=250):
        self._animation = QtCore.QVariantAnimation(
            duration = duration,
            valueChanged = self.setPos,
            startValue = self.pos(),
            endValue = next_pos)
        self._animation.start(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.DeleteWhenStopped)

class GraphicsView(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GraphicsView, self).__init__(parent)
        _scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(QtCore.QRectF(-250, -250, 500, 500), self)
        self.setScene(_scene)
        self.scene().addRect(self.sceneRect(), brush=QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.green))
        polygon = QtGui.QPolygonF()
        polygon << QtCore.QPointF( 10, 10 ) << QtCore.QPointF( 0, 90 ) \
                << QtCore.QPointF( 40, 70 ) << QtCore.QPointF( 80, 110 ) \
                << QtCore.QPointF( 70, 20 )

        self._interval = 300

        self.poly_item = GraphicsPolygonItem(polygon)
        self.poly_item.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.red))
        self.scene().addItem(self.poly_item)
        timer = QtCore.QTimer(self, interval=self._interval, timeout=self.on_timeout)
        timer.start()

    def on_timeout(self):
        p = QtCore.QPointF(
            random.randint(self.sceneRect().left(), self.sceneRect().right()), 
            random.randint(self.sceneRect().top(), self.sceneRect().bottom()))
        self.poly_item.moveTo(p, self._interval)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = GraphicsView()
    w.resize(720, 720)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a try.

Comment: Sorry I am taking long to reply. I have implemented and it works great. Thank you for the help.